# readonly transaction with Spanner R2DBC and Spring Data

Tags: google-cloud-spanner, spring-data-r2dbc

Is there a possibility to use read-only transactions with Spring Data R2DBC and especially with Google Spanner DB Backend? RO-transactions are supported in the Spanner R2DBC driver and offer much scalability advantage (no locking!). However, it is not R2DBC standard and I haven't found any support for this in the Spring Data R2DBC documentation.

Comment: Hmm good question. Looks like if you're able to access the R2DBC connection object, you'll be able to downcast it to `SpannerConnection` and be able to specify a custom transaction type in the overloaded `beginTransaction(TransactionOptions o)`: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-spanner-r2dbc/blob/master/cloud-spanner-r2dbc/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/r2dbc/SpannerConnection.java#L85

I'm not sure how to access this from Spring Data R2DBC though... will do some research.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my research it looks like this is not possible yet.

I filed a feature request asking to support extended features in Spring Data R2DBC here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-spanner-r2dbc/issues/314

The goal will be to allow you to make read only transactions using the Transaction annotation, like:

```
@Transactional(readonly = true)
public void readAndSaveRecords(..) {

}
```